# How does Exchange 2007 behave if the InternalUrl property of a virtual directory is set to $null?

Tags: exchange, exchange-2007

I have a CAS server that is expected to only be accessed from the outside. I currently have it configured with both the InternalUrl and ExternalUrl properties set to the same external URL. I'm wondering if it would be better to set InternalUrl to $null.

I understand that the InternalUrl and ExternalUrl properties have a strong effect on CAS proxying and redirection, but I haven't been able to find any documentation which will explain what happens if the InternalUrl is set to $null.

Additionally, if anyone has any recommendations on where I could find documentation or a book that would do a serious deep dive on Exchange behavior, I would be grateful.

Answer (score 0):

The "InternalUrl" parameter specifies the URL that is used to connect to the virtual directory from inside the network firewall. If set to null, the internal outlook client may encounter issue when connect to Exchange server. By default, the internalUrl will be existed as the FQDN of the CAS server after installation completed, it's not recommended set it to null.

Best Regards,